# Robert Rankin book featuring a Norse warrior and a giant pouch of tobacco with a flying pen

Tags: story-identification

This is an obscure memory from a Robert Rankin story I now want to track down and read again.

IIRC there is a paragraph or two in the opening chapters where this happens...

A Norse warrior type is at a fiord when he glances up, a large pouch of tobacco is floating in the air, together with a giant pen..

He excitedly points this out to his companions because he knows 'his author' is writing him into a new adventure

That's really all I remember, want to get this book again but don't want to order  book after book until I strike lucky.

Does anyone have all of his books and know which one it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's from one of the **Armageddon trilogy** which starts with "Armageddon: The Musical", most likely the first one but I have none handy to check.

The character is Rambo Bloodaxe who remarks: "It's Rankin, he's in the pub again and he's writing."

Comment: Thanks for the major clue. I downloaded all three Armageddon books and it turned out to be the second one "They came and ate us"  I originally stated a tankard of ale but it was a pouch of tobacco so I have edited my question